# Google vision api vs build your own

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, image-recognition

I have quite a challenging use case for image recognition.  I want to detect composition of mixed recycling e.g. Crushed cans,paper,bottles and detect any anomalies such as glass, bags, shoes etc.

Trying images with the google vision api the results are mainly "trash", "recycling" "plastic" etc likely because the api hasn't been trained on mixed and broken material like this?.

For something like this would I have to go for something like tensor flow and build a neural network from my own images? I guess I wouldn't need to use google for this as tensor flow is open source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So generally, when ever you apply machine learning to a new, real world use case, it is a good idea to get your hands on a representative dataset, in your case it would be images of these trash materials.

Then you can pick an appropriate detection model (VGG, Inception, ResNet), modify the final classification layer to output as many category labels as you require (maybe 'normal' or 'anomaly' in your case, so 2 classes).

Then you load the pre-trained weights for this network, because the learned features generalize (google 'Transfer Learning'), initialize your modified classification layer randomly, and then train the last layer, maybe train the last two layers, or last three layers (depending on what works best, how much data you have, generalization) etc.

So, in short:
1. Pick a pretrained model.
2. Modify it for your problem.
3. Finetune the weights on your own dataset.

Comment: Thanks. And in terms of a representative dataset, would I use images of bottles, card, glass as separate images or images of trash all together and somehow code the anomalies within it?

Comment: Representative, as in the images it would see, if it were deployed in the real world. So if you are panning to take images from a trash camera mounted above a trash conveyor belt, get a few hundred images from that camera, annotate it, and that's your dataset. This is ofcourse the ideal case, you would get the best accuracy from this.
You can however try training something like a Faster RCNN on the individual images, but I don't expect the localization (finding 'where' the object is) to work well.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks alot